# Streaming MP3 with pre-processing

Tags: html, streaming, html5-video, audio-streaming, html5-audio

I was wondering if there's a way to get streaming audio data (mp3, flac, arbitrary chunks of data in any encoding) from a server, process it and start playing after first chunk?

> **Background**: All of our data is stored in compressed chunks, with a LAMP environment serving the data. de-compression and re-assembling is done client-side with
>   xhr-downloads, indexeddb, filehandle and/or chromefs. All currently
>   available audio/video functionality requires the audio to be
>   downloaded completely (otherwise decodeAudioData fails) or requires an
>   URL to the source without giving me a chance to process incoming data
>   client-side.

I am looking for a solution to squeeze my processing into the browser "inbuild" streaming/caching/decoding functionality (e.g. audio/video tag). I don't want to pre-process anything server-side, I don't want flash/java-applets and I'd like to avoid aligning data client-side (e.g. process mp3)

Question: Would it be possible to dynamically "grow" a storage that a bloburl points to? In other words: Create a filehandle / fileentry, generate a blobURL, feed it into an audio tag and grow the file with more data ?

Any other ideas?

Michaela

***Added**: Well, after another day of fruitless attempts, I must confirm that there are two problems in dealing with streamed/chunked mp3|ogg data:*

*1) decodeAudioData ist just too picky about what's fed into it. Even if I pre-align ogg-audio (splitting at "OggS" boundaries) I am unable to get the second chunk decoded.*

*2) Even IF I would be able to get the chunks decoded, how would I proceed playing them without setting timers, start positions or other head-banging detours? Maybe the webAudioAPI developers should take a look at aurora/mp3 ?*

***Added**: Sorry to be bitching. But my newest experiments with recording audio from the microphone are not very promising either. 400K of WAV for a few seconds of recording? I have taken a few minutes to write about my experiences with webAudioAPI and added a few suggestions - from a coders perspective: http://blog.michaelamerz.com/wordpress/a-coders-perspective-on-the-webaudioapi/*

Comment: You can't start playing after the first chunk.  Each format has its own framing.  How much data you need before you start playback depends entirely on the codecs and container formats.  Beyond that, the WebAudio API is what you need.

Comment: Thanks Brad - I am aware of this, though aurora.js with mp3.js is perfectly happy to start playing after the first chunk. Our chunk sizes are between 100 and 300 Kbytes. With Webaudio, I can't feed arbitrary chunks into decodeAudioData, because it will fail if the data is not aligned. I would like to use WebAudioApi - but it's not an options as long as the decoder fails to do what it is supposed to do :)

Comment: You need to decode the codec yourself and feed it to the WebAudio API.  The WebAudio API is the only real way to write audio to the sound device with JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry Brad, but this is silly. Why would I need to decode common audio myself, if the browser has all the codecs built-in? Wouldn't it make much more sense if "decodeAudioData" would be more robust to be able to decode it itself? I am not arguing against WebAudioAPI - but it doesn't make any sense if it can't stream common audio like MP3 or OGG.

Comment: Sure, the browser is fully capable of doing this for you except that you're refusing to use the built-in features, making it not possible.  The WebAudio API deals in PCM only, so if you want full control of your own buffering and audio playback, you will need PCM samples.  To get that, you have to use a JavaScript codec.  If you would simply serve your audio up via HTTP, this wouldn't be an issue.  It's easy enough to create streams server-side sent via HTTP, and you can dynamically control them over websocket or whatever.

Comment: Well, WebAudioAPI provides decodeAudioData to do just that: Decode known audio types into PCM. aurora/mp3 is able to align arbitrary chunks correctly - why can't decodeAudioData? I don't want to control my own buffering or anything else, I just want to work with what's available: Chunks of mp3|ogg|whatever data. It shouldn't be the job of the javascript-developer to think about codecs if all that would be necessary is a little more "brain" built into decodeAudioData.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout https://github.com/brion/ogv.js. Brion's project chunk-loads an .ogv video and outputs the raw data back to screen through WebAudio API and Canvas, playing in the original FPS/timing of the file itself.

There is a StreamFile object in the codebase that handles the chunked load, buffering and readout of the data, as well as an example of how it is being assembled for playback through WebAudio.

I actually emailed Brion directly for a little help and he got back to me within an hour. It wan't built for exactly your use case, but the elements are there and I  highly recommend Brion who is very knowledgeable on file formats, encoding and playback.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `<audio>` tag for this. However, what you can use

- [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web_Audio_API) - allows you dynamically construct audio stream in JavaScript
- [WebRTC](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/) - might need the streamed data pre-processing on the server-side, not sure

Buffers are recyclable, so you can discard already played audio.

How you load your data (XHR, WebSockets, chuncked file downloads) really doesn't matter as long as you can stick the raw data to a JavaScript buffer.

Please note that there is no universal audio format the browsers can decode and your mileage with MP3 may vary. AAC (mpeg-4 audio) is more supported and it has best web and mobile coverage. You can also decode AAC using pure JavaScript in Firefox: http://jster.net/library/aac-js - you can also decode MP3 in pure JavaScript: http://audiocogs.org/codecs/mp3/

Note that localStorage supports only 5 MB data per origin without additional dialog boxes, so this severely limits storing audio on the client-side.

Comment: Thanks Mikko. However, WebAudioApi has problems with decoding arbitrary chunked data, as decodeAudioData fails if the file hasn't been downloaded fully or at least has been aligned client-side. I did some testing with aurora.js and mp3.js but its not really reliable and it doesn't make too much sense to decode an audio-stream in JS if the browser is perfectly able to do that itself.